# Replace a loop to implement Contains on an array

Tags: c++, stl

Is there a way to use the Standard Library to simplify the loop on an array of struct that compare with strncmp?

Below is my attempt that fails because std::count_if complains there is no instance of overloaded function std::begin matches.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

struct nodeobject
{
    CString ObjectType;
    nodeobject() {}
    explicit nodeobject(CString objectType) { ObjectType = objectType; }
};

struct nodeinput
{
    struct nodeobject Object;
};

// Original function I want to rewrite to remove the for loop and the strncmp
static int ContainsObjectType(int collectionSize, struct nodeinput collection[], char* objectType)
{
    auto found = 0;
    for (auto idx = 0; idx < collectionSize; idx++)
    {
        if (strncmp(objectType, 
                    collection[idx].Object.ObjectType, 
                    strlen(collection[idx].Object.ObjectType)) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

#if 0
// The implementation below does not compile because there is no instance of 
// overloaded function std::begin matches
static int ContainsObjectType(int collectionSize, struct nodeinput collection[], char* objectType)
{   
    auto numFound = std::count_if(std::begin(collection),
                                  std::end(collection),
                                  [](struct nodeinput oneNode) 
    { 
        return strncmp(objectType, oneNode.Object.ObjectType, oneNode.Object.ObjectType) == 0); 
    });

    return numFound > 0;
}
#endif

int main()
{
    struct nodeobject node1("fokker");
    struct nodeobject node2("airbus");
    struct nodeobject node3("boing777");
    struct nodeinput collection[] = {node1, node2, node3};
    auto nintnode = 3;

    auto found = ContainsObjectType(nintnode, collection, "boing777");

    std::cout << found << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

> C2784: const _Elem *std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Elem>) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for 'std::initializer_list<_Elem>' from 'nodeinput []

Comment: please provide the exact error message

Comment: First of all, do you want to _count_ the number of objects that satisfy `strncmp(...) == 0` or return 1 if there is such an object or zero otherwise? `ContainsObjectType` does the latter, but the new version attempts to do the former.

Comment: Considering using `std::string` and it's methods instead of `CString` and c string functions. You do not need to specify `struct` every time you use a `struct` type. Consider using standard containers instead of arrays, doing so would eliminate your problem.

Comment: I want to return 1 if there is one object of the type. The error is C2784: 'const _Elem *std::begin(std::initializer_list<_Elem>) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for 'std::initializer_list<_Elem>' from 'nodeinput []'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make `collection` a pointer, maybe a `const` one:

```
static int ContainsObjectType(int collectionSize, struct nodeinput *collection, char* objectType)
{   
    auto numFound = std::count_if(
        collection,
        collection + collectionSize,
        ...);
}
```

`std::count_if`'s two first arguments must be iterators, and pointers *are*, in fact, primitive iterators.

`std::begin(iterable)` is merely `pointer`, `std::end(iterable)` is `pointer + <data length>`.

Comment: It would be worth mentioning that `std::begin` and `std::end` work with arrays but not if they decayed to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

Below the complete solution in case someone searches how to replace a c-style loop on an array of objects with the library standard.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "afx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Legacy code
class NodeObject
{
public:
    CString objectType;  // Keeping CString to minimize the impact for now
    NodeObject() {}
    explicit NodeObject(CString objectType) : objectType(objectType) { }
};

// Legacy code
class NodeInput
{
public:
    NodeObject object;
    explicit NodeInput(NodeObject object) : object(object) { }
};

// Code using vector and count_if
static int Contains(std::vector<NodeInput> collection, std::string objectType)
{
    auto numFound = std::count_if(std::begin(collection),
        std::end(collection),
        [&](const NodeInput oneInput)
    {
        return (std::strncmp(objectType.c_str(),
                             oneInput.object.objectType,
                             strlen(oneInput.object.objectType)) == 0);
    });

    return numFound > 0;
}

// Code using array pointer and count_if
static int Contains(int collectionSize, NodeInput* collection, char* objectType)
{
    auto numFound = std::count_if(collection,
                                  collection + collectionSize,
                                  [&](const NodeInput oneInput)
    {
        return (std::strncmp(objectType,
            oneInput.object.objectType,
            strlen(oneInput.object.objectType)) == 0);
    });

    return numFound > 0;
}

// Legacy code
static int ContainsOriginal(int collectionSize, NodeInput collection[], char* objectType)
{
    auto found = 0;
    for (auto idx = 0; idx < collectionSize; idx++)
    {
        if (strncmp(objectType, 
                    collection[idx].object.objectType, 
                    strlen(collection[idx].object.objectType)) == 0)
        {
            found = 1;
        }
    }
    return found;
}

int main()
{
    // Legacy code
    NodeInput arrayCollection[] { NodeInput(NodeObject("fokker")), 
                                  NodeInput(NodeObject("airbus")), 
                                  NodeInput(NodeObject("boing777")) };
    auto arrayCollectionSize = 3;
    auto found = Contains(arrayCollectionSize, arrayCollection, "boing777");
    std::cout << found << std::endl;

    // Code using Standard Library
    std::vector<NodeInput> collection{ NodeInput(NodeObject("fokker")),
                                       NodeInput(NodeObject("airbus")),
                                       NodeInput(NodeObject("boing777")) };
    found = Contains(collection, "boing777");
    std::cout << found << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```